# The expression doesn't evaluate to function, so it can't be invoked?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ShoppingListState extends State<ShoppingList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> shoppingItems = new List();
    shoppingItems.add("pain");
    shoppingItems.add("tomate");
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemCount: shoppingItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,i) {
          return Text(shoppingItems(i));
        }
    );
  }
}
```

The error is on `return Text(shoppingItems());`

Answer (score 0):

`shoppingItems` is not a function but a `List`, you might want to access the element at the `i` position so you replace your code using `shoppingItems[i]`.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it did solve your issue